# Coldfusion Hash with SHA-1 vs Php sha1

Tags: hash, coldfusion-10, railo, cfml

I have tried to encrypt the some string using sha-1 in coldfusion 10 and php.

coldfusion code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="Mydata">
abcdefghijklmn
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset data = Hash(Mydata,"sha-1") >
<cfdump var="#data#" abort="true"/>
```

Coldfusion OutPut:
 113D1951E36C83FE1F60BF3BC520CEF65E0373BE

PHP code:

```
$content_digest = sha1('abcdefghijklmn');
var_dump($content_digest);
exit();
```

PHP OutPut:
 85d7c5ff403abe72df5b8a2708821ee33cd0bcce

Both code didn't produce the same output.

And I have tried online tool for SHA-1 http://www.freeformatter.com/sha1-generator.html#ad-output

Site OutPut: 85d7c5ff403abe72df5b8a2708821ee33cd0bcce

That site and php code are produce the same output.

Anyone explain please what is going wrong in my cf code? Thank you.

Comment: Could CF perhaps include whitespaces/newlines in the input?

Comment: Yes You are correct.

Comment: @SimonSvensson - Good spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<cfsavecontent>` introduced some extra whitespaces.

So just use

```
<cfset data = Hash('abcdefghijklmn',"sha-1")>
```

Run it yourself: http://trycf.com/gist/21e6b5b1ee87f858b913/acf

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfsavecontent variable="Mydata">
abcdefghijklmn
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset data = Hash(trim(Mydata),"sha-1") >
<cfdump var="#data#" abort="true"/>
```

Using trim() function I got correct output.

Output: 85D7C5FF403ABE72DF5B8A2708821EE33CD0BCCE

Comment: Yep, with hashing, any difference is significant, including case and white space.  Side note, since the php code produces lower case, you might also want to `lcase` the resulting string for an exact match on case.